# Push Notification receive on device after deleting it from ionic.io

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, push, ionic.io

I create push notification with push http api, after that i delete created push notification with uuid.

After deleting it still receiving on the device.

Any help?

Comment: what do you mean by deleting push notification? Are you deleting the triggered push notification or are you deleting the device id from the list? If you are deleting device id, it will receive the notification because it is triggered when the device id is in the list.

Comment: @varunaaruru I create push notification by POST https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications, after it registers , I am deleting it with DELETE  https://api.ionic.io/push/notifications/, and  DELETE https://api.ionic.io/push/messages/. After deleting the message and notification it still receive on the device